# Solving the differential $\frac{y'y'''}{y''} = x$

Tags: calculus, integration, ordinary-differential-equations, analysis, differential

I've been trying to solve the differential equation: $\frac{f'(x)f'''(x)}{f''(x)} = x$, $x\in \mathbb{R}$

My initial attempt was to integrate by parts, something like this:

$$\int_{}^{} \frac{f'(x)f'''(x)}{f''(x)} dx = \int_{}^{}x dx \Leftrightarrow \\ ln(f''(x))f'(x) - \int_{}^{} \ln(f''(x)) f''(x)dx  = \frac{x^2}{2} + C1$$

but I soon came to realize that there was absolutely no way to proceed. Even if I try to reduce it to a second-order nonlinear ODE by letting $u(x) = f'(x)$, I can't seem to solve it by simple integration.

After some trial and error, I managed to figure out that $f(x) = \frac{x^3}{3} + C ,x\in \mathbb{R}$ (as noted by @Vasili) is indeed a solution (if not the *only* solution) to this differential.

And here I ask you: How do we mathematically prove that $f(x) = \frac{x^3}{3}$ + C is a solution? How do we reach that conclusion without simply making guesses?

Thanks in advance for any insight!

Comment: You can substitute $u=y’$ and decrease the order of the differential equation. Try plugging in $\frac{x^3}3$ into the differential equation to test if it is a solution.

Comment: @TymaGaidash As I've already mentioned, I have tried substituting u = y', but even if the order decreases, I still don't see a way to solve it. And x^3/3 is a solution to the original equation. The problem is how do I prove it mathematically? How do I perform the necessary math operations to solve for f and find x^3/3?

Comment: what's your initial conditions?

Comment: @MathFail None, it's simple: Solve for f(x).

Comment: without initial conditions, how do you know your solution is right?

Comment: You can prove it's a solution by substituting into the ODE. However $f(x)=\frac{x^3}{3}+C$ is also a solution. I am thinking representing $y$ as Taylor series may help solving this ODE.

Comment: @MathFail because it works if you plug it in. But that's beside the point, the point is that we are NOT supposed to know the solution. How can we find it algebraically?

Comment: @Vasili How are we supposed to represent y as a Taylor series when we do not know y? Do we do it for some arbitrary function y?

Comment: @ApparentlyPlus: we do not need to know $y$, Taylor expansion is using derivatives at a specific point. For example, around zero we can express $y(x)=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}y^{(n)}(0)\frac{x^n}{n!}$

Comment: Aside from $y=c_0$ and $y=c_0+x^3/3$ there are two other general solutions. They are $y=c_0+c_2x^2+x^3/6+...$ where $c_2\ne 0$ and $y=c_0+c_1x+c_2x^2+0x^3+...$ where $c_1\ne 0$.

Comment: I used $y'y'''=y''x$ as the DE. Using $y'y'''/y''=x$ eliminates $y=c_0$ as a solution. Also for $y=c_0+c_1x+c_2x^2+0x^3+...$ assume also $c_2\ne 0.$

Comment: Taking $f'_x=x^2\xi(\tau)$, $\log(x)=\tau$, and $\xi'_\tau=p(\xi)$ the problem is reduced to an Abel equation of the second kind
\begin{align}
pp'_\xi+(3-\xi^{-1})p=2(1-\xi).
\end{align}

Comment: As written the function doesn't seem to have a nice general solution. Is the differential equation perhaps supposed to be $$\frac{y'y'''}{(y'')^\color{red}{2}} = x,$$ which can be resolved with elementary techniques but which isn't *too* simple?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

My idea is to assume that $y$ is an $n$-th degree polynomial, which means
$$
\deg\left(\frac{y'y'''}{y''}\right) = \deg x \\
\Rightarrow (n-1) + (n-3) - (n-2) = 1 \\
\Rightarrow n = 3
$$
So our $y$ is a 3rd degree polynomial, which means we can write it in this form
$$
y = Ax^3 + Bx^2 + Cx + D, A \not = 0
$$
Now what's left to do is to find the coefficients, given that
$$
\frac{y'y'''}{y''} = x
$$
We can plug in our polynomial expression for $y$ and get
$$
6A\cdot\frac{3Ax^2 + 2Bx + C}{6Ax + 2B} = x \\
\Rightarrow 6A \left(\frac{1}{2}x + \frac{B}{6A} + \frac{C - \frac{B^2}{3A}}{6Ax + 2B}\right) = x \\
\Rightarrow 3Ax + B + \frac{6AC - 2B^2}{6Ax + 2B} = x
$$
And from here, it's easy to see that
$$
A = \frac{1}{3} \\
B = C = 0
$$
So in conclusion, our solution to this DE is
$$
y = \frac{1}{3} x^3 + D
$$

Comment: This is indeed the easiest to comprehend answer, but how exactly can we assume that the answer is a polynomial? Couldn't it be some other expression?

Comment: It indeed can be some other expression. This is just one case of the equation where I did an assumption so that it becomes easier to deal with.

Answer (score 0):

The differential equation to be solved is
$$ \frac{f'(x)f'''(x)}{f''(x)} = x. \tag1 $$
One way to do this is
[the method of undetermined coefficients](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Method_of_undetermined_coefficients).

Assume that $\,f(x)\,$ has a power series expansion
$$ f(x) = c_0 + c_1\frac{x}{1!} +c_2\frac{x^2}{2!} + c_3\frac{x^3}{3!}
 + \dots \tag2 $$
where $\,c_0, c_1, \dots\,$ are constants to be determined.
For convenience, rewrite equation $(1)$ as
$$ a_0 + a_1\frac{x}{1!} +a_2\frac{x^2}{2!}+\dots :=
  f'(x)f'''(x) - x\,f''(x) = 0 \tag3 $$
with the proviso that $\,f''(x)\ne 0.\,$
Expand the derivatives of $\,f(x)\,$ in series to get
$$ a_0 = c_1c_3,\; a_1 = c_1c_4+ c_2(c_3-1),\;
 a_2 = c_1c_5 +2c_2c_4 +c_3(c_3-2), \; \dots \tag4 $$
From here it is a case by case analysis. That is, $\,a_0 = 0\,$ iff
$\,c_1=0\,$ or $\,c_3=0.\,$ The cases are:

I. $\,c_1=0.\,$ Now $\,a_1 = c_2(c_3-1) = 0\,$ iff
$\,c_2=0\,$ or $\,c_3=1.\,$

Ia. $\,c_1=0, c_2=0.\,$ Now $\,a_2 = c_3(c_3-2) = 0\,$ iff
$\,c_3=0\,$ or $\,c_3=2.\,$

Iai. $\,c_1=0, c_2=0, c_3=0.\,$ After this point, all other
coefficients must equal zero. This implies $\,f(x)\,$ is the
zero function which makes equation $(1)$ undefined.

Iaii. $\,c_1=0, c_2=0, c_3=2.\,$ After this point, all other
coefficients must equal zero. This implies $\,f(x) = c_0 + x^3/3\,$
which is verified as a solution.

Ib. $\,c_1=0, c_3=1.\,$ Now $\,a_2 = 2c_2c_4-1 = 0\,$ which
implies that both $\,c_2\,$ and $\,c_4\,$ are nonzero. After
this points all other coefficients are determined. The result is
$$ f(x) = c_0 + t\frac{x^2}{2!} + \frac{x^3}{3!} +
 t^{-1}\frac12 \frac{x^4}{4!} - t^{-2}\frac16\frac{x^5}{5!} -
t^{-3}\frac18\frac{x^6}{6!} + t^{-4}\frac25\frac{x^7}{7!} -
t^{-5}\frac{67}{144}\frac{x^8}{8!} + \dots \tag5 $$
where $\,t\ne 0\,$ and the pattern of coefficients is not evident.

II. $\,c_3=0.\,$ Now $\,a_1 = c_1c_4-c_2 = 0.\,$ If $\,c_1=0\,$
then $\,c_2=0\,$ and this is case Iai again. Thus, assume $\,c_1\ne0.\,$
After this point all other coefficients are determined. The result is
$$ f(x) = c_0 + u^{-1}\frac{x^1}{1!} + t\frac{x^2}{2!} + tu\frac{x^4}{4!}
- 2t^2u^2\frac{x^5}{5!} +3u^2 t(1+2ut^2)\frac{x^6}{6!} + \dots \tag6 $$
where $\,u\ne 0\,$ and the pattern of coefficients is not evident.